# Flutter rest api mapping query

Tags: flutter, api, rest, mapping

```
`      Future<List<GetEntityKindModel>> getGroups() async {
        List<GetEntityKindModel> data = [];
        try {
          var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
          print('Before mapping $response');
          print('hhh --- ${json.decode(response.body)}');
          data = List<GetEntityKindModel>.from(json
              .decode(response.body)
              .map((x) => GetEntityKindModel.fromJson(x)));
    
          print('\nHoli');
          print('data-----${data.first.name}');
        } catch (e) {
          print('err-$e');
        }
        return data;
      }

`
```

Please help. Why is a null list being returned as the data, instead of a non-null list? The API response has non-null data, I checked it from the console by printing it. I want the data to return as a non-null list, not a null list. Here GetEntityKindModel is the model class generated from the API response using quicktype.io.

```
1) Tried tweaking the assigning of mapping to data unsuccessfully to below:
data = json.decode(response.body).map((e) => GetEntityKindModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
2) Tried returning a specific attribute of data instead of whole data but it doesen't really solve the issue


Here is my model 

        class GetEntityKindModel {
      GetEntityKindModel({
        required this.name,
        required this.description,
        required this.role,
        required this.status,
        this.parentGroup,
        this.visibility,
        required this.permission,
        required this.configureHeaderOptions,
        required this.id,
        this.parentEntityId,
        required this.languageId,
        required this.entityIndex,
        this.ip,
        this.ipStatus,
      });
    
      String name;
      String description;
      String role;
      bool status;
      int? parentGroup;
      Visibility? visibility;
      int permission;
      List<dynamic> configureHeaderOptions;
      int id;
      int? parentEntityId;
      LanguageId languageId;
      List<String> entityIndex;
      String? ip;
      String? ipStatus;
    
      factory GetEntityKindModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetEntityKindModel(
        name: json["name"],
        description: json["description"],
        role: json["role"],
        status: json["status"],
        parentGroup: json["parentGroup"],
        visibility: visibilityValues.map[json["visibility"]]!,
        permission: json["permission"],
        configureHeaderOptions: List<dynamic>.from(json["configureHeaderOptions"].map((x) => x)),
        id: json["id"],
        parentEntityId: json["parentEntityId"],
        languageId: languageIdValues.map[json["languageId"]]!,
        entityIndex: List<String>.from(json["entityIndex"].map((x) => x)),
        ip: json["ip"],
        ipStatus: json["ipStatus"],
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "description": description,
        "role": role,
        "status": status,
        "parentGroup": parentGroup,
        "visibility": visibilityValues.reverse[visibility],
        "permission": permission,
        "configureHeaderOptions": List<dynamic>.from(configureHeaderOptions.map((x) => x)),
        "id": id,
        "parentEntityId": parentEntityId,
        "languageId": languageIdValues.reverse[languageId],
        "entityIndex": List<dynamic>.from(entityIndex.map((x) => x)),
        "ip": ip,
        "ipStatus": ipStatus,
      };
    }
    
    enum LanguageId { EN_US }
    
    final languageIdValues = EnumValues({
      "en_US": LanguageId.EN_US
    });
    
    enum Visibility { GROUP_ENTITIES, ALL_ENTITIES, OWN_ENTITIES }
    
    final visibilityValues = EnumValues({
      "All Entities": Visibility.ALL_ENTITIES,
      "Group Entities": Visibility.GROUP_ENTITIES,
      "Own Entities": Visibility.OWN_ENTITIES
    });
    
    class EnumValues<T> {
      Map<String, T> map;
      late Map<T, String> reverseMap;
    
      EnumValues(this.map);
    
      Map<T, String> get reverse {
        reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
        return reverseMap;
      }
    }
```

Comment: make sure code paste as code not as a image also paste your model

Comment: also check this link for more details https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: Done both @Abhijith

Comment: I followed all steps in the link @Abhijith. I have fetched and displayed the api response in another class. I don't know why after the mapping in this controller class not even the static statement to print "Holi" isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls share the api response as well from Postman or some other API call platform for better understanding and provide the solution

like the response of https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 is :

```
{   "userId": 1,   "id": 1,  "title": "delectus aut autem",  "completed": false}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have solved the issue. Thanks again anyways